# What device information am I allowed to transmit?

Tags: ios

I cannot find Apple documentation or guidelines as to what device information I am allowed to transmit and save on my server. I remember reading that sending UDID was a big no-no. I don't care about a unique identifier, but I'd like to send basic device information and the system time zone. Am I violating any policy by sending the information below? A link to policy (if it exists) would also be lovely.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[params setObject:device.name forKey:@"deviceName"];
[params setObject:device.systemName forKey:@"deviceSystemName"];
[params setObject:device.systemVersion forKey:@"deviceSystemVersion"];
[params setObject:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone].description forKey:@"deviceSystemTimeZone"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [App Store EULA](http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/appstore/dev/stdeula/)

> b. Consent to Use of Data: You agree that Application Provider may collect and use technical data and related information, including but not limited to technical information about Your device, system and application software, and peripherals, that is gathered periodically to facilitate the provision of software updates, product support and other services to You (if any) related to the Licensed Application. Application Provider may use this information, as long as it is in a form that does not personally identify You, to improve its products or to provide services or technologies to You.

The data you describe is sufficently anonymous, except for `UIDevice.name` which is likely to contain the user's name (and might even contain the user's full name). If you actually want the device model, use UIDevice.deviceModel or the corresponding `sysctl()` to get the underlying model string (e.g. "iPhone3,1" for the iPhone 4).

The debate over whether the UDID is personally identifying is approximately equivalent to the debate over whether IP addresses are personally identifying — they often are if you have additional information.

Answer (score 1):

All these fields are allowed. There are some frameworks for getting such statistic (like [http://localytics.com](http://localytics.com/) or [flurry.com](http://www.flurry.com). As far as they are allowed to send this, you allowed too. Also, you can just use one of them to get needed info from your app without making your own server-side solution.

Comment: Thanks for links to the frameworks. I would up-vote but I can't yet.